What happens if I inject power to 5V rail which connects to a 7805 output?
I happen to have an old circuit board which regulates power with a 7805 from 9VDC power supply input.
I want to make it USB-C powered and inject 5V to the 5V rail directly through a port it has, and I don't want to modify or desolder anything (want to keep it original).
The 5V rail is directly connected to the output of the 7805 so if I inject 5V, the 7805 will receive power on its output.
Is this a problem? Will it damage the regulator?

is the 9V still going to be connected at that point?

The 7805 can be damaged by having its output pin at a higher voltage than its input pin. This usually occurs if the input voltage is suddenly lost and a charged capacitor on the output feeds voltage back through it. A diode connected across the input and output with cathode towards the input is usually recommended to protect against this as can be seen in Figure 7 of this datasheet. It states that reverse voltages of 7 V or greater can damage the regulator, the diode limits it to around 0.7 V. You might be okay with 5 V without a diode, but it's a bit questionable. Your device may have a diode already, you can examine the board and see. Ultimately it's a matter of how much you want to risk damaging it.
As others have mentioned you also have to worry about damaging the USB by connecting it to a circuit that's not compliant. You might be able to get a USB-C compliant 5V to 9V boost converter that could power your device.

That would protect the 7805 indeed. But not the USB supply from getting hot-plugged into potentially non-compliat device. There is just too many dangerous scenarios to make this a good idea having USB connector paralleled with 7805 output.

What happens depends on the details of the circuit.
The regulator likely leaks output voltage to input. Some regulators tolerate a 7V difference from output to input before requiring an external reverse bias protection diode. Depending on exact 7805 type, it might not handle that much and damage, because the input capacitor is charged through the regulator in reverse.
Even if you remove the 7805, another issue is that you don't know if the result is USB compliant. USB devices are required to limit inrush energy, and in addition to resistive load maximum, the hot-plugging capacitance limit is 10uF.
A 5V power supply might not care much, but damag may happen if you plug a non-compliant amount of capacitance to your computer by accident.
So either nothing happens, or the regulator damages, or the Type-C source damages, or both damage.
In general, it would be a bad idea to simply connect Type-C 5V VBUS to the 7805 5V output without further consideration.
A further problem is if there  is 9V into 7805 turned on accidentally while also connected to USB. It will short circuit the 7805 5V output with the USB 5V output to the device. It is forbidden and unexpected by USB standards for that to happen and can further damage the USB supply source, which may be accidentally your expensive PC instead of USB power supply.

It's unlikely to damage the 7805 because it wants to naturally produce 5 volts. However, if the 7805 is naturally producing (say) 5.1 volts (there's always an upper and lower limit) and the USB port naturally produces 4.9 volts then, the 7805 might try and power the USB port and get in a sulk and shut-down on thermal overload.
This may or may not cause some performance issues on the target load.

So as long as I monitor the heat of the regulator when plugged in, and see it's stable, should be ok?

I'm not sure what monitoring of the temperature will do. The chip will shut-down (not break) if it overheats and monitoring is just... monitoring. The question is this: can your target load suffer cyclical changes in the regulated voltage between two different levels due to thermal effects. In extremes this could be 4.75 volts to 5.25 volts.

I mean, if it's hot to the touch means it's overloading, which I wouldn't be comfortable with, even if it shuts down

There are other problems than the 7805 getting overheated and shut down. For example it may destroy your expensive PC before 7805 overheats and shuts down.
